# Cast from interface to class, bad design or small violation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a question on how to be in cases when I build the hierarchy on interface, then I have the base abstract implementing class and many subclasses - concrete implementors.
But say one of the subclasses has 2 extra properties that are not included in the interface. But I need them when I work with interface. Is it a bad practice to cast from interface to the direct concrete class? Or maybe I would formalize this case (2 extra properties not included in interface) as a new extension of base interface through inheritance, 
when one interface inherits from another one, so it would be safe to cast not to class, but to derived interface. What choice is the most corrective?

Here's an example:

```
public interface IToken {
     string Tag {get;}
     string Content {get;}
     object CalculatedValue {get; set;}
     string ValueFormat {get;}
}

// inheritance of interface
  public interface ISimpleToken: IToken {
       string Key {get; set;}
  }

// OR!!!!!
  class SimpleToken: IToken {

    // ....interface members

    ....
    public string Key {get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: "It depends". Sometimes it's 'better' to use the more generic interface and refine to a specific implementation in specific code. In such cases I generally weigh the 'cost' of carrying along unnecessary signatures and of other guards that the program will remain valid, even if it cannot be statically enforced.

Comment: Please provide us a basic example of what you're talking about, rather than describing it.

Comment: As @user2864740 says, it can be a code-smell, or, sometimes, it can be the right thing to do.  In any case, may sure that you code for a cast failure (and use `is` or `as` not a `(SomeType)`-style cast (i.e. that throws on failure)).  You might also find this useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement.  There's an equivalent "pattern matching" if statement syntax now as well: `if (myObj is MyType myTypeObj) {  }`

Comment: I added a sample code

Comment: In this case I'd *probably* have `ISimpleToken` *anyway*, but it still doesn't help with dealing with a `List<IToken>`, and desiring to call `Key`, eg, as one would still need to get an `ISimpleToken` (or `SimpleToken`; adding the interface is secondary to refining the type).

Comment: The way you have it formatted seems correct. If you simply want to build a derivative of the first interface that includes a couple more properties, then creating another interface is more correct. If you plan on building functions that depend on the members from your original function, then it would be better to just use a class. The "is-a" vs "can-do" relationship for this type of stuff is a good way to think about it. Here's a link to a similar topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688808/should-one-interface-inherit-another-interface

Comment: @RippStudwell Can you please provide more example on how to find differences between "is-a" vs "can do"? As for my code, it's published on GitHub. https://github.com/nikolayresh/TextExtensionsNet/tree/master/src/TextExtensionsNet.Library/Tokenization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is if you are going to expose your API through interfaces, you should uses interfaces throughout. Your interfaces should only include things you want to publicly expose. If it's something you just need inside of the implementation of that interface it goes in the class.

The other part, "it depends". Usually with the way you are headed, at some point, you're going to want a collection of all of those implementations and so you would need to refer to them by the common base interface/class.

EDIT: if you find that you need to cast interfaces from the base class, you are "probably" doing something wrong. If multiple interfaces have the same method, it belongs in the base interface. You can do this with generics.

If you have a scenario where the derived classes need to do something different from the base class, then you should use virtual methods and overrides.

Adding something into a derived class is fine as long as it doesn't change the interface which it shouldn't since if you are using interfaces, you generally don't want to expose the implementation classes.

Comment: So, as I understood - small violations and fragile design are fully accepted inside code that is not public to the client and if I'm 100% sure that the cast will succeed?

Comment: @NickReshetinsky Code owes nothing that is not promised :)